# Sharepoint 2010 and Samba LDAP groups

Tags: sharepoint, samba, ldap, sharepoint-2010

The setup:

- Windows 2008 SP2
- Sharepoint 2010 Foundation
- Samba 3 "Domain"

I'm trying to use the Samba LDAP users & groups we already have to access to Sharepoint.

I can successfully authenticate using the Samaba accounts (getting the "Error: Access Denied" message as the user has no permissions).  So Sharepoint can clearly see and use the existing accounts/groups.

[Signed In but Access Denied http://www.medstv.unimelb.edu.au/sf/acc-den.jpg](http://www.medstv.unimelb.edu.au/sf/acc-den.jpg)

What I can't do is be authorised as in the grant permissions interface, Sharepoint now fails to match the account (I get an "No Exact match found...").

[Permissions - can't find account http://www.medstv.unimelb.edu.au/sf/permisions.jpg](http://www.medstv.unimelb.edu.au/sf/permisions.jpg)

Is there a way of getting the Sharepoint permissions interface to recognise and use our existing Samba LDAP accounts?

I get it - don't use Samaba, use AD.  If I had that option I would, but I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add a custom membership provider? LIke in the following article:

http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/articles/MOSS2007-and-Novell-LDAP-Authentication.aspx